# plotting 3d graph by stacking 2d contour plots in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have got two different variables x and y that are both functions of variable z. I have multiple contour plots of x vs y at different z values. What I want to do is put these graph slices together along z axis to get a 3D-ish graph.

I searched for packages that lets me do this in R and all I could find was contourrslice in Matlab. Contourslice is exactly what I want but in R.
Is there a package/ function in R like contourslice or any other ways I could go about doing this?

EDIT: Here's a dummy data. For different values of z the heat map changes. I have these several 2D plots, for values of z from -1 to 15. I want to put these 2D plots together along z axis to get a 3D ish figure to see how the red area is displaced.

```
#Create range of values for x and y
x<- c(11,25)
y<- c(1,5)
length<-10
x_ran <- as.matrix(seq(x[1],x[2], len=length))
y_ran <- as.matrix(seq(y[1],y[2], len=length))

#initialise matrix
x_mat<- x_ran[,rep(1,length)]
y_mat<- t(y_ran[,rep(1,length)])

#Third variable z
z<- -1
#z<- 1
#z<-2
#z<-3

#R and C, funcition of z
R <- x_mat*z
C<-z-y_mat

toget<- R/C 
image(toget, xlab="R", ylab="C")
```

Comment: Package recommendations are discouraged on SO. If you had example data there might be reason to exert more effort.

Comment: are you looking for a 3d figure containing just the contours or one where there is interpolation between the contours as well?

Comment: Adding close vote for no response after 6 hours for request for  example data. That should not have been very difficult to provide.

Comment: @BondedDust added example data. Sorry didn't reply sooner, nighttime here in the uk so went to sleep after posting question.

Comment: @nongkrong i just want to get 3d figure for now, but if there is a way to intrapolate I would like to do too